# change form field value on submitt action extjs

Tags: extjs, form-submit, extjs3

I have form with extjs like this:

```
        {
            xtype : 'textfield',
            fieldLabel : 'name',
            name : 'vTitle',
            allowBlank : false
        },{
            xtype : 'datefield',
            fieldLabel : 'name',
            name : 'date',
            allowBlank : false
        }
```

when I submit form value send to server like this:

```
Parameters:
 vTitle:mm
 date:9/11/2011
```

When I submit the form I want my own value to send instead of the default value. For example when I submit the date: `9/11/2011` I want the date: `my value related with 9/11/2011` sent to server.

I used setvalue for my form but if I have error from server my default form value's changes and I do not want use setvalue.(only I want send my own value to server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url:'requestURL.ajax',
    params:{
       // date: 'your modified date' OR date: date.getValue(), or whatever you want..
    },
    success: function(response, options){

    },
    failure: function(resp, action){

    }
});
```

It will make an Ajax call, and you will be able to send any parameter inside it, and also you can handle its response inside success & failure..

Answer (score 5):

You can do it by setting `submitValue` to `false` on this two fields, and by creating hidden field which will contain computed value. When you set `submitValue` to `false` value from field won't be submited as name implies, so only hidden field value will be submited. So you only need to create handler to update value in hidden field (for example you can create handler for `Ext.form.BasicForm.beforeaction` event).

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/3zmvJ/2/